# Need to insert a string based off numeric values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan, numeric

I have the following dataframe

```
cols = ['Name', 'Production']
data = [['Well1', '0'],
        ['Well2', '1200'], 
        ['Well3', '300'], 
        ['Well4', '600'], 
        ['Well5', '100']
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

    Name Production
0  Well1          0
1  Well2       1200
2  Well3        300
3  Well4        600
4  Well5        100
```

I need to insert a new column named 'Rating' and assign it a string based off the production value. 
The conditions I need are

```
rating is 'R1' if production is >= 850
          'R2' if <= 150
          'R3' if > 150 and < 850
          'na' if =0
```

What I've tried

```
bopd = [
        (df['Production'] >= 850),
        (df['Production'] <= 150),
        (df['Production'] > 150) & (df['Production'] < 850),
        (df['Production'] == 0)
        ]
ratings = ['R1', 'R3', 'R2', 'na']
df['Rating'] = np.select(bopd, ratings, default='none')
```

In the dataset I'm working with, it says dtype: float64. I tried this exact code (changed column names), and I get the following error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I've tried using df.astype(str).astype(int) and I still can't get my conditions to work.

Comment: your code works after `df.Production=df.Production.astype(int)` you set the Production as int , or if there are strings in that column better would be `df.Production=pd.to_numeric(df.Production,errors='coerce')`

Comment: i get this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'

Comment: try the second option in the comment , you have strings (invalid numbers in the series)

Comment: df.Production=pd.to_numeric(df.Production)

Comment: that worked - I had tried that already but was missing the beginning df.production =.